# Can I (in a many to many relationship) select only those id:s in column A that has a connection to all id:s in column B?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to retrieve only those id's in "A" that has a connection to all id´s in "B".

In the example below, the result should be '***...fa3e***' because '***...65d6***' does NOT have a reference to all id´s in "B".

[image]
However, if '***...fa3e***' and '***...65d6***' reference the same id's in column B, then the query should return both '***...fa3e***' and '***...65d6***'.
[image]

And, subsequently, if a fifth row would connect '***...fa3e***' with a completely new id in "B". Then '***...65d6***' would be excluded because it no longer holds a reference to all id's in column "B".

Is there a way to accomplish this in SQL server?

I can´t really come up with a good description/search term of what it is I´m trying to do ("Exclude column A based on values in column B" is not quite right). Hence I´m striking out looking for resources.

Comment: The given example very confusing, why the third is OK while the second is not? please write the expected result in a separate part.

Comment: I updated my question to be more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe these values reside in the same table.

For distinct `a` values only:

```
select a
from T
group by a
having count(distinct b) = (select count(distinct b) from T);
```

To return all the rows:

```
select * from T where a in (
    select a from T group by a
    having count(distinct b) = (select count(distinct b) from T)
);
```

If `(a, b)` pairs are always unique then you wouldn't need the `distinct` qualifier on the left-hand counts. In fact you could even use `count(*)` for that.

Comment: I updated my question to better depict the desired end result.

Comment: @fboethius Did you not try my answer?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like it's going to be a terrible query, but at it's most basic, you want

- All A where B in...
- All B that are fully distinct

In SQL, that looks like

```sql
select distinct A
from test
where B in (select B from test group by B having count(1) = 1);
```

Absolutely zero guarantees on performance, but, this gives you the right value A. If you want to see which A/B pair actually made the cut, it could be `SELECT A, B FROM test...`  too.

Comment: ...If in the image there were 4 rows and both A values were linked to both B values, then `group by B having count(1) = 1`  will always be false and the query returns no rows...

Comment: @lptr That's correct. The OP specifically requested **unique** B's. The only way both A values could be linked to both B values is if B appears twice. If a B appears again in row #4, then it should not be returned, per their specifications. If I am otherwise mistaken, please provide the exact example, and we can have the OP validate what their preferred result be.

Comment: @CoffeeNeedCoffee I updated my question to be more specific regarding the desired end result. I gave you an upvote because you did provide a solution based on original specs.

Comment: Oh, that updated clarification is wildly different than what I interpreted originally..